# How can I athenticate dockerpy using gcloud API?

Tags: gcloud, gcloud-python, dockerpy, google-cloud-python

I have tried to push a Docker Image to "gcr" Registry programmatically. The "gcloud docker --authorize-only" gives me a short - live authentication.

How can I perform authentication using python gcloud API without shell execution?

Comment: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/stable/resource-manager-api.html